# What is the difference between different ways of getting WebDriver in Selenide?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenide

In Selenide, as I know there is at least 2 ways of getting WebDriver instance:

1. Selenide.webdriver() which calls -> WebDriverRunner.getSelenideDriver().webdriver()
   and
2. WebDriverRunner().getWebDriver()

So what is the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

`Selenide.webdriver()`

As you mentioned the above method in turn called `WebDriverRunner.getSelenideDriver()` to get already created static instance of selenide in which webdriver object instance present to return it.

`WebDriverRunner().getWebDriver()`

It will return `WebDriver` object only if we set external driver object using `WebDriverRunner().setWebDriver(driver)`